# High capacity batteries

Tags: weapons, starfinder

It mentions on page 168 that lower capacity batteries still work in more powerful weapons so long as they have enough charges. The rules appear to be mute on whether you can purchase a better battery for a lower-level weapon (like having an extended clip in real life). Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RAW, no**

> Capacity: A weapon's capacity measures the largest-capacity battery it
>   can hold (given in number of charges)

(Starfinder Core Rulebook pg 170)

This wording is consistent with other mentions of replaceable batteries (SCR 170, 190, 203, 204, 218).